# Geological/Geographical term for the point where different waters meet/conflux?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

If you would like to describe a place where two different waters meet together and form a new stream, what word would you choose? I looked it up online and found word "**confluence**" can be the choice but I got the feeling that it is  describing about the phenomenon of the conflux rather than the geographical feature of the stream.

That being said, I don't think saying like

> XXXX stream is a water confluence
>
> or
>
> XXXX confluence(conflux) is named because it is where two different water bodies meet

will successfully describe what I intend.

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you look it up? The [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confluence) article clearly lists the 'place where the rivers meet' sense as well as the 'flowing together and becoming one stream' sense. I've checked two other dictionaries, and they list the feature sense first.

Answer (score 2):

Confluence is correct. This wikipedia entry for [Koblenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koblenz) is a good example of how to use it correctly.

Comment: For further confirmation, Google "at the confluence" with the quotes